# this.state.file.name not rendering as a react element

Tags: reactjs, state, render

I have a drag and drop field (called `react-dropzone`) that `setState` of a `file`.

I want the `file.name` to be rendered in the browser.

When tested, it produces no errors nor results. I can get other states to render in the normal way. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
class Home extends Component {
state = {
fileName: {}
};

handleOnDrop = file => {
this.setState({ file });   
};

render() {
return (
<div>
<Dropzone onDrop={this.handleOnDrop} </Dropzone>

<h3>{this.state.file.name}</h3>

</div>
);}}

export default Home;
```

Thanks!

EDIT: The answer is that I was trying to pass a full array to a value not set up to take an array. In this case, I needed to pass a single element (file name) from file array to the state.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/new , can you create a sandbox demo for us so we can debug? include the component code as whole.

Comment: The answer below was accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*onDrop* returns an array of accepted files.

```
handleOnDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
  acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file.name);
  })
}
```

[Docs](https://react-dropzone.js.org/)

Comment: I used this part of the code, `acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file.name);
  })`, worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer, and I don't know if you pasted the whole code, but a closing tag is missing  on your `Dropzone` component.

A sandbox demo would help imo

Comment: Thanks but the dropzone component is the input. The onDrop function handles the input, and the h3 tags are for the output.

Comment: I meant for this line

   `<Dropzone onDrop={this.handleOnDrop} </Dropzone>`

You are calling the closing `</Dropzone>` while you have `<Dropzone ` with no closing `>`

Comment: Ohh, I see. Must have deleted that when inputting it into stackoverflow. Thanks